# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: in weblogic

Tags: java, spring, maven, weblogic

when making a deployment in weblogic I get the following error.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:      javax/validation/spi/ConfigurationState.getParameterNameProvider()Ljavax/validation/ParameterNameProvider;
```

Do I exclude any dependencies?
I think the problem is bean-validator

**pom.xml**

```
jersey-guava-2.6.jar
jersey-client-2.6.jar
jersey-common-2.6.jar
jersey-server-2.6.jar
jersey-spring3-2.6.jar
jersey-media-json-jackson-2.6.jar
jersey-container-servlet-core-2.6.jar

bean-validator-2.2.0.jar
novedades-validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar
hibernate-validator-4.2.0.Final.jar
validation_1.0_spec-1.1.jar

hibernate-core-3.6.7.Final.jar
transactions-hibernate3-3.7.0.jar
hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar
hibernate-entitymanager-3.6.7.Final.jar
hibernate-commons-annotations-3.2.0.Final.jar
```

**weblogic.xml**

```
<container-descriptor>
    <prefer-application-packages>
        <package-name>org.hibernate.*</package-name>
        <package-name>javax.validation.*</package-name>
    </prefer-application-packages>

    <prefer-application-resources>
        <resource-name>javax.validation.*</resource-name>
        <resource-name>org.hibernate.*</resource-name>
    </prefer-application-resources>
</container-descriptor>
```

Thank you

Comment: Which version of WebLogic?

Comment: WebLogic version 11g

Comment: This is commonly an issue with either a missing transitive dependency, and more often the version of the dependent jar is incorrect and not compatible (Signature of the method is different).

Answer (score 0):

This issue can occur due to `incompatible` version of `validation api` being used.

Also check if there are `2 versions of validation api in the class path`.

Run a `mvn dependency:tree` command to check for inter dependencies.